# Can't logon to domain controllers

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2019

We have 2 domain controllers with 2019 server, system administrator made something with GPO which deny access for group "Domain Admins" to workstations, now it is distributed throughout the domain (including domain controllers and servers). He aslo made changes to Active Directory Users and Computers (like include domain admins to Protected user group, deny delegation for domain admins in profiles, reset krbtgt password).

GPO was like:

```
 Deny access to this computer from the network
 Deny log on as a batch job
 Deny log on as a service
 Deny log on locally
 Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services user rights
```

error:

```
Logon failure: user account restriction. Possible reasons are blank passwords not allowed,logon hour restrictions, or a policy restriction has been enforced.
```

So we can't logon to domain controllers or other servers/workstations with domain admin logins. All remote control is also blocked.
I don't know if it's just the GPO or something else (because if viewed remotely, the GPO should not be applied to the OU with domain controllers)

I did Authoritative Restore (DSRM) of all AD, didn't worked, i see that sysvol folder still have this GPO (files deleted but folder structure preserved). Also all changes made to AD still preserved (like Domain admins users still in Protected users group) Why are these changes not rolled back?

gpupdate /force from workstations show error cause gpt.ini from this GPO not exist and group policy cannot be apply.

Any help please?

Comment: Did you run MMC and attempted to edit the GPO remotely?

Comment: `I did Authoritative Restore (DSRM) of all AD`. From what date was the backup restored, and what backup application was used?

Answer (score 0):

This solution should be easy: use the known utilman trick to get a shell with system permissions. Add a new user "admin" from there. make him member of the group "administrators" (not domain admins). Logon as admin. Download psexec (pstools from microsoft). Now start mmc as system account:
psexec -s -i mmc
add GPMC to that mmc
Do the changes. System may do anything on a DC!

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was in changing password for user krbtgt.
Solved this way: Disabled the rest of the domain controllers (even if I did an Authoritative Restore, my domain controller took data about this user from others domain controllers) then made Authoritative Restore again and change password few times for this user and all works

Comment: consider, on a restore to disable network connectivity! :D